# Dual monitors will only display in mirrored mode; How do I configure the second one as an extended desktop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 14.04, asus

Recently I installed 14.04 on:

- ASUS A88XM-A MoBo
- AMD A10 7700K CPU
- 32G Ram.

The kernel version is:
  - 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My video connections are through the integrated video connections of the MoBo (not a separate video card).  My HDMI Monitory is a SAMSUNG 27 SyncMaster. Yesterday I purchased a Benq sensey 27 now connected to the DVI-D with single link cable.

The problem is both monitors are mirrored.  Displays shows only one monitor pink colored (Built-in Display) and below that Built-in Display is pink, the on/off switch is greyed and set to on.  Mirror displays is greyed as well appearing to be unchecked. Resolution is 1920x1080(16:9) launcher placement is all displays.

Nothing happens when I click the Detect Displays.  Please help me understand how to turn off mirroring in a dual monitor configuration.

Do not really know what I am looking fro her, but in **/var/log/Xorg.0.log** this looks interesting:

```
[    22.952] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    22.952] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    22.952] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    22.952] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.952]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[    22.952]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    22.952] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    22.952] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.952] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    22.952] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    22.952] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.952] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    22.952] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    22.952] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
```

also, only one of my monitors is listed in this log:

```
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Monitor name: S27B550
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Number of EDID sections to follow: 1
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): EDID (in hex):
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  00ffffffffffff004c2d1b093034355a
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  22160103803c22782af711a3564f9e28
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  0f5054bfef80714f81c0810081809500
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  a9c0b3000101023a801871382d40582c
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  450056502100001e011d007251d01e20
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  6e28550056502100001e000000fd0018
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  4b1e5111000a202020202020000000fc
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0):  00533237423535300a2020202020014d
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): EDID vendor "SAM", prod id 2331
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[    22.994] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
```

Comment: Please could you post a link the to Motherboard manual.  What chipset does the motherboard use for the video?  nVidia, AMD (ATI), Intel?  You may need to install different drivers.  How much RAM do you have configured for video?

Comment: Please post `xrandr` output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch into 2D mode
Worked fine for me